# Authorization has been denied for this request - Azure Active Directory - What logs are available?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

So I'm using postman with the OAuth 2.0 process to try to authenticate against my WebApi over Azure Active Directory. I am still on the default project with the basic ValuesController, just trying to get authentication and authorization to work.

I've followed [this video](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devkeydet/2016/03/22/using-postman-with-azure-ad/) to setup postman, and as far as I can tell, I've configured the new applications in active directory as described.

The token exchange is working. And the Authorization Bearer {token} is being sent correctly. Here is an example token:

{Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlliUkFRUlljRV9tb3RXVkpLSHJ3TEJiZF85cyIsImtpZCI6IlliUkFRUlljRV9tb3RXVkpLSHJ3TEJiZF85cyJ9.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.NXpvslBXOpRNkmWQqj7XqVzloS3KoeSqPIlo-yUPGYkZ4bHPrAH6yD4sxMYz-19VIPFRDUMP-5h5hmaMKmuykjNUltz6wejQT9f4IeV6i7VtP3BlkfASZeAdKAiSjKh6ydV8PuJjV2HHh2WvxIKC3QQXzROwWAdeXLcgMTiKSBMULzFV8BsecgtI86_L2OISgbQZ2LgF137EPJoG7C4L1IO-10T1QIVl-Emy6AS0VKVxdzjCgiT-DFtccxME6n1CruoDy6mTKztcAkiFR1IlgY6Fvj-Y_goMQyxA5sCRebWnOQ5jeUKv4KNyNWOLJU_RiZYe0kj4IT3KDc9jjtHykg}

However, even though I get the token successfully and when I step through the debugger in VS, I see the token coming in, Authorization is failing. I get the following response:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

The issue seems to be on the server side. When I override IsAuthorized to return true, it works.

In Azure, both applications are in the same directory with delegate permissions on.

Are there any logs I can check to see the exact denial reason? From there I can probably figure out what is going on.

I've turned on tracing, with:

```
// Web API configuration and services
var traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
traceWriter.IsVerbose = true;
traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Debug;
```

But it's not really telling me why I get the denial.

Comment: Looking at my WebApi i see my _Audience_ defined as `https://{tenant_name}.onmicrosoft.com/{webapi_name}`, i have the same value in the Azure AD page for __App ID URL__. Just mentioning this since  getting 401 Unauthorized with a token that looks valid at first glance is most likely tied to the _Audience_ setting.

Comment: `{webapi_name}` == the name of your WebApi entry in Azure AD

Comment: @evilSnobu. Hi, sorry for the slow response. Thanks for the feedback. I tried that and no dice. Any other ideas?

Comment: The good news is that your token looks identical to mine. However i'm accessing the Web API with a Native App (as defined in Azure AD). Request sample: http://pastebin.com/raw/Rwx2KP7D. Can you provide maybe a few screenshots or verbatim on how you've defined both your apps in Azure AD?

Comment: And here's how both my Native App and Web Api are setup in Azure AD: http://pastebin.com/raw/1vaWUeGT

Comment: @Ayo I I had a quick scan through the video and couldn't see that it showed you how to configure your service to get the public key from azure ad to validate the token signature as well as unpack it onto a claims principal, how have you done this part?

Comment: @evilSnobu So I ended up deleting all of the applications in that directory, and simply starting from scratch with a new directory. That time it worked. Leads me to believe that some previous tinkering with the active directory, left it in a bad state. (For example, one of the applications I created still can't be deleted. Will probably need to send a ticket to Azure support to get that application and entire directory deleted.) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the Azure AD Directory was somehow corrupted. I think maybe something went wrong with an original concept app that I created. For whatever reason, I cannot delete that app in the Azure portal, and thus can't delete the directory itself.

However, creating a brand new directory, unfortunately, seemed to fix it. I followed all of the same directions.

The only difference, is I added the following to the Web.config: `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="buckets_api.Startup"/>`. Whereas, last time I added: `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>` to address an api startup issue I encountered with the new template. However, I don't believe that is what resolved the issue.

On a side note, I also noted that Chrome was unable to complete the token exchange in the popup browser without me re-launching the app as admin. I'm not sure if that was also related, as I was getting tokens before, so I don't think so. But I want to document what worked for me in its entirety, in case someone else encounters this in the future.

Comment: Did you have any response from Azure support regarding this issue? I started having same problem recently with one of my tenant ADs, but unfortunately I cannot delete my AD instance and recreate.